# Ask permission on f5

Tags: flash, refresh

I've just been listening to music in http://listen.grooveshark.com/ website and tried to refresh the page and then it gave me message "Do you really want to refresh this page?". How is this done?

Comment: Sounds like a Javascript event to me.

Comment: Javascript.  Is there anything it can't do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

Comment: Actually it is not exactly what I'm searching for, because now it always gives me an error when I click on link. I want that it only would gave me it, when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

It probably uses the `window.onunload` event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload